# Print 2D list with each number right justified

Tags: python, format

I need to print a 2D list row by row with each numbers in the list right justified. I used nested loops and formatting but failed. How can I change the code?

```
def print_suqare(square):
    for line in square:
        for i in line:
            print(str(i).rjust(10), sep = " ")
```

I expect that a list like

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

should print as

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
```

Comment: I mean I want to print a 2D list line by line. for each line each number should be right justified and there is a space between each number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code adds a newline from the `print` call for every cell, causing every element to appear on its own line. You can pass the named parameter `end=""` into `print`, then manually add newlines after printing each row:

```
def print_square(square):
    for line in square:
        for i in line:
            print(str(i).rjust(10), end="")

        print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_square([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Or you can use `*` to unpack the list as in the next example and optionally use the `sep` named parameter. It's also nice to parameterize the pad amount and give it a default value, increasing reusability.

```
def print_square(square, pad=10):
    for line in square:
        print(*[str(i).rjust(pad) for i in line], sep=" ")
```

Or you can use `join`:

```
def print_square(square, pad=10):
    for line in square:
        print(" ".join(str(x).rjust(pad) for x in line))
```

Alternately, you can dynamically determine the padding based on the longest element:

```
def print_square(square):
    pad = max(len(str(x)) for y in square for x in y)

    for line in square:
        print(" ".join(str(x).rjust(pad) for x in line))
```